# How can we create functions in odoo

Tags: odoo-8

I want to create functions for odoo 7 version fields but main thing is that new  functions I want to create in odoo 8.please any one help me If any Example it is Good.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please explain what are you trying to say.

Comment: My aim is to create function to filter the data.Example fields like project_id and user_id this fields are in V7.I am inherit that V7 code and create the function in V8. I tried for couple of times but the function is not working in V8.Can you please provide the solution.

Comment: can you paste your code here so that I can see where the problem is